# how to get the data from the tableAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, tableadapter

I'm using a dataset and web service and in my web service method I call and execute the procedures that I have created in the database so my question is 
I have the result from the database but I didn't know to use or call the data itself.

how can I do that?

I tried searching but all the results that I reached were about the connection string that I don't want use. this is my first time using dataset and web service so maybe I was searching with wrong key words.

here is my code and the last line is where I stopped and didn't know how to continue.

newCityTable has the result of the procedure.

```
 OrderDatasetTableAdapters.getCityNameTableAdapter newOrder = new OrderDatasetTableAdapters.getCityNameTableAdapter();
        newOrder.GetCityNameData();

        OrderDataset.getCityNameDataTable newCityTable;
        newCityTable = newOrder.GetCityNameData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer and here I will share it with everyone. maybe someone will find it helpful.

```
string city;
// i here refers to the variable in a for loop. you can do whatever you want before like using loop, fetch a specific row or create an array..etc but this is the way to get the data that you want
city = (string) newCityTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the follow (without a conversion to an item array) which may be more efficient:

```
city = newCityTable.Rows[i].Columns[0].ToString();
```

or in general if you had a double for loop:

```
city = newCityTable.Rows[i].Columns[j].ToString();
```